# Increase spacing between action buttons?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, spacing

This is my `menu.xml` at the moment

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_save"
        android:title="Save"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_save"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_delete"
        android:title="Delete This"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_delete"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

However, the spacing between the overflow menu and the main Save button is pretty small. I'd like to add more spacing.

Here is my `styles.xml`

```
<resources>

    <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- ... -->
        <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton">
        <item name="android:paddingEnd">100dip</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">100dip</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">100dip</item>
        <item name="android:horizontalSpacing">100dip</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ... -->

</resources>
```

Unfortunately, that style has no effect.

The only thing I can get to work is `<item name="android:minWidth">300dp</item>`. I am using this for now, but the problem is I am going to have various buttons of different widths, so it would be much better if I could set spacing or padding instead of min-width.

Why are all of my padding rules of `100dip` not working, and what should I do instead?

Comment: create custom action bar...

Answer (score 0):

Found solution, added following lines in styles.xml file and it worked!!

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionButtonStyle" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:minWidth">20dip</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dip</item>
</style>
```

Comment: padding `0dip`? *"it would be much better if I could set spacing or padding instead of min-width"*

Comment: I tried setting `android:padding` to `20dip`, and it did have an effect. Unfortunately the text is cropped because it is setting padding on all sides. I need to only add horizontal (left and right side) padding.